# error when generating html document with ggplots on remote R server using ReporteRs package(.:18048): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:

Tags: linux, r, ggplot2, reporters

I installed ReporteRs package on a remote linux server and try to generate HTML pages with it. It works fine, but when trying to add a ggplot to the document it gives this error:

```
(.:18048): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
```

I used the solution for these kinds of problems mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25992088/linux-how-to-run-a-program-of-gtk-without-display-environment-gtk-warning), (running "export DISPLAY=:0.0", before running R), but there still is an error. Now it says:

```
(.:19674): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0.0
```

Now I am wondering if there is a way to alter the addPlot() function in such a way that it doesn't want to display anything, but just wants to put it in the document?

I use the addplot() function like this:

```
data <- structure(list(x = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", 
"9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", 
"20"), y = c(142, 316, 223, 319, 61, 155, 400, 384, 183, 342, 
308, 167, 20, 506, 310, 164, 66, 221, 368, 345)), .Names = c("x", 
"y"), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
library(ReporteRs)
library(ggplot2)

mydoc = bsdoc( title = 'My page' )
graph <-  qplot(data$x,data$y, data)
mydoc = addPlot( mydoc, fun = print, x =graph,vector.graphic = TRUE, width = 12,par.properties = parLeft(padding = 5)) 
writeDoc( mydoc, file = "/mypage.html" )
```

Is there a solution or work around for this problem? Many thanks in advance!

*EDIT* There is a work around. First I save the plot as an image with ggsave(). Second I use addImage() of the ReporteRs package to add this image to the document. This is rather ugly because it takes much more time to process.

*EDIT2* I did some more investigation. It has something to do with X11 device. Now I am wondering how to use X11 without the need for displaying. Could this be possible with an R code?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will not be the only one who will connect. I hope to find a solution in the ReporteRs code itself.

Comment: Yes I understand. Sorry for not being clearer, but we are trying to add the system to a web application and I was told that your solution is not the way to go.

Comment: The code you've posted works without error for me. I'm using Scientific Linux 6 with a connection over SSH and no DISPLAY set. This is with the current CRAN release of ReporteRs (0.7.8) and R 3.2.1.

Comment: Do you mean set the display like this "export DISPLAY=:0.0"? I use this linux Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)

Comment: I meant that on my remote server it works fine even without DISPLAY set. If you're still having trouble, one option if you have admin privileges on the box would be a dummy X driver per instructions at http://askubuntu.com/questions/453109/ubuntu-14-04-add-fake-display-when-no-monitor-is-plugged-in  . These would need adapting for other distros.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am not that skilled in server related ussues. I wil discuss it with my server administrator.