# How to stop R programmatically from opening display on linux remote server?

Tags: linux, r

I started off with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31207085/error-when-generating-html-document-with-ggplots-on-remote-r-server-using-report) issue, but I think my question is in fact: is there a way to stop R (installed on a remote linux server) programmatically from opening a display when e.g. using plotting functions? I don't have administrator rights, so I am looking for a solution using R scripts only. Is that even possible?

The problem that I encounter is the error I get every time R wants to use a display. This is te case with plotting functions, but also when updating some R packages, e.g. updating ReporteRs 0.7.6 to ReporteRs 0.8.2. The error I keep on getting is:

```
(.:<some code>): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
```

After this error R stops running.

I have already tried with no success:

```
options(device=NULL)
```

Some system info:
linux Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit),
R version 3.2.1

Comment: You could connect with `ssh -X` and thereby redirect the graphics display to your local computer.

Comment: Interesting suggestion. This R environment will be used by many different users, with server connections from different machines. So I don't  think this will be the solution.

Comment: open a PNG to plot to, or use Xvfb (x virtual frame buffer) ?

Comment: Thanks ben. However, I don't think that would solve the package  installation problems.

Comment: Maybe I was too quick with my response. I will check Xvfb out.