# Visual Studio Linux GTK-WARNING **: cannot open display

Tags: linux, visual-studio, ssh, gtk

I believe this has to do with an issue where an ssh connection cannot open a window unless it has X11Forwarding enabled (which I do) and you set the DISPLAY variable in your ssh connection.

Seen a lot of threads like this
[(Linux) How to run a program of gtk without display environment? Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25992088/linux-how-to-run-a-program-of-gtk-without-display-environment-gtk-warning)

Exact error in its entirety says

```
(Display window:3622): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
```

Is there any ways to send these commands to set the display or -X to enable forwarding on the ssh connection? I'm trying to write an opencv application for an Odroid chip and would like to develop in Visual Studio if possible, but this has made me hit a snag because I can't see my image results being created on the remote machine (which has a display I can see) without working out this issue.

Edit:

Well I'm a dummy the answer is in the option @

Configuration Properties -> Debugging -> Pre-Launch Command

type in the following command

```
export DISPLAY=":0"
```

Comment: did you use -Y flag on ssh call?

Comment: Visual Studio initializes the session all by itself, I'm not sure how to change any parameters about it. However, there is a section you can launch any terminal commands before it starts the program so that is the best solution I have found so far

Comment: @ChaseRLewis could you please post an answer yourself stating the points you followed to solve this?